# Unit testing ASP.net Web API with IPrincipal set

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to unit test a Web API controller. Previously when unit testing a standard MVC controller, I have been able to Mock the HTTPContext/Request/User and insert them by setting the controller context. However this doesn't work with a Web API Controller (The constructor for ControllerContext does not accept a Web API obviously).

So far I have the following to set the request object.

```
HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();

controller.Request = request;
controller.Request.Properties["MS_HttpConfiguration"] = configuration;
```

This works fine, and the request object is useable. However I can't find any way around setting the Principal user. I have tried the following

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = //Set User
HttpContext.Current = //Set User
```

Neither of which work it seems.

Comment: Use Selenium or similar. You cannot mock everything.

Comment: When you say "been able to Mock", were you using a mocking framework?

Comment: Yes, we are using Moq/NUnit.

Comment: Can you please specify the Api method you trying test? What exactly the behaviour you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

In more recent version of web api you can set the user directly on the `ApiController` Like so

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetReturnsProduct()
{
    // Arrange
    var username = "username@example.com"
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new CustomIdentity(username));
    var controller = new ProductsController(repository);
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
    controller.User = user;


    // Act
    var response = controller.Get(10);

    // Assert
    Product product;
    Assert.IsTrue(response.TryGetContentValue<Product>(out product));
    Assert.AreEqual(10, product.Id);
}
```